# Look like the blog link is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, broken-link

[Celebrating the Stack Exchange sites that turned 10 years old](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/18/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-10-years-old)

[image]

The page is not found on this link, also I am not able to find the correct link from https://stackoverflow.blog

Comment: Related MSE post/comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368730/please-remove-area-51-discussions-from-the-celebrating-se-sites-that-are-10-y#comment1230137_368730

Comment: Archived copy if anyone wants to see the "before editing" version: https://web.archive.org/web/20210818135309/https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/18/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-10-years-old/

Comment: Also reported on MSE: [What happened to this link? Celebrating 10 years](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/368737/289905).

Comment: This has resolved itself automatically when the side bar cache was updated.